# What's a good way to set up a development environment on OS X for ruby, rails, and git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, development-environment

I'm going to start development on a web app using ruby, rails, probably either postgres or mysql, and most likely apache. I'll be using a git repository with the master repo on another server.

I've searched through stackoverflow and done some Googling... so here's what I have so far...

What are your opinions on what's described on this page?: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805668/2009-rubyists-guide-to-a-mac-os-x-development

What about this one?: http://www.buildingwebapps.com/articles/79197-setting-up-rails-on-leopard-mac

I don't need helping finding an editor, there's plenty out there (TextMate, TextWrangler, MacVim), but I do need help to make sure I'm setting things up correctly to code, build, and run the web app from my mac.

Here's a specific set of scenarios I could use some help on:

- Testing various versions of rails and/or ruby.
- Testing performance, vulnerabilities, monitoring queries, etc.
- Testing different versions of gems.
- Working on other projects on this same machine.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these articles mention rvm which is probably a "must have" for testing multiple versions of rails/ruby

Comment: Oh I forgot about that! It was mentioned at the local ruby group meetings, but thank you for the reminder. :)

Answer (score 1):

These aren't really the things you should be worrying about at this point. Rails promotes rapid development. Until you actually launch the site SQLite/webrick will more than adequate for building the application.

I understand the desire to set things up perfectly before you start development, but I'd encourage you to just dive in and worry about those things later.

That being said, I would set up git. Not enough can be said on the value of using version control.

Comment: I already use git at my current job and I love it. I'm not entirely worried about the prod environment at the moment and I have a sysadmin helping me out with that anyway.

Do you have any advice for general dev/testing/etc for the various versions of ruby, rails, and gems?

Comment: What's your experience level with Ruby?

Comment: Beginner. I've been checking out some books on both ruby and rails. I want to dive into some code and get started on the web app.

During the last 4-ish years I've been developing in a few languages (Perl, Java, VB.net) on a variety of platforms and development environments.

Comment: I would say just do that for the time being. It's easy to get overloaded with specifics when learning something new. Do the fun stuff first and as the needs for the above arise, tackle them individually. Edit: I know that doesn't answer your question, and I apologize. Was just giving some related advice. :)

Comment: I'd just like to add I *just* got my first project under version control (using Git) and it is just awesome to visualize branch history!

It is definitely worth the time to get Git setup and working properly :-)!

Comment: Git is a must. I would never start a project without it.